# how call BI Publisher report from Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, bi-publisher

how can I  call bi publisher report from apex. 
bi publisher 11.1.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Tyler Muth has covered this topic. You will have to setup an SQL connection from BIP to your APEX (via TNS). Then you will have to write the SQL for Apex system on BIP and setup a report. Then you can use the runReport method of BIP's generic WSDL to invoke that report from Apex.

https://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/call-bi-publisher-web-services-from-apex/

Its not easy, you will have to debug a lot of stuff yourself.